# Help identifying airfield and aircraft from movie "My Spy"

Tags: aircraft-identification, airport-identification

Here's a couple of stills from the movie "[My Spy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Spy)" - the climactic scene takes place at a single-strip airfield with a paved or tarmac 09 runway.

My tentative identification of the (clearly unflyable) military planes in the background, from left to right: an Avro CF-100, a F-86 Sabre, then a two seat F-104, and next (judging from the tail) another single seat F-104 in unusual light green camouflage.

The red and white plane in the background, from a later shot, is an F-5 in unusual livery.

The second picture points to the F-86 being RCAF, which would point to a Canadian airfield. On the other hand, the furthest F-104 looks very much to be in [Belgian colours](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Lockheed_%28SABCA%29_F-104G_Starfighter%2C_Belgium_-_Air_Force_AN2059463.jpg).

There's not much more to go on! I wondering **where this is**, and how these planes ended up there.

[image]

[image: Still from My Spy]

"My Spy" 2020 Amazon Films / STXfilms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The film was shot in and around Toronto, so a search of local airfields on Google Maps led me to [Markham Airport](https://goo.gl/maps/Q3X8dDXXEqDnVCVAA). From there, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markham_Airport) provided this list of military aircraft on the field:

CT-128 Expeditor transport

CT-133 Silver Star

CF-5 Freedom Fighter

CF-104 Starfighter (Various Airforces)

Canadair CL-13 Sabre

Schweizer SGS 2-33A Royal Canadian Air Cadets[citation needed]

Noorduyn Norseman - shell only

The aircraft belong to the Canadian Air, Land and Sea Museum. Looking at the satellite image on Maps it would appear that a number of other aircraft have been stored there, but have now been removed.

There's a clutch of rather more complete airframes in amongst the buildings in the south west corner of the airfield.

[image]
<sup>[Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/Q3X8dDXXEqDnVCVAA)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

I might be a little late to the party, but my daughter just convinced me to watch this movie a couple of days ago and, being RCAF for the last 30 yrs, I noticed the red & white CF-5 right away. It’s an old 419 “Moose Sqn” colours bird. I saw it several times when I was posted to Cold Lake, AB. Sad to see these old hulks in such disrepair.

Answer (score 3):

“My Spy” 2020 was mostly shot in the Toronto area and the airport scene was shot at the [Markham Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markham_Airport) near Toronto.

[image]

Comment: By picking a different part of the airport to grab a screen shot of, they could be totally different places on Earth!